# How to understand the derivative of vector-value function with respect to matrix?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

function: $  f = A\cdot b$

gradient: $  \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = b^\top \otimes \mathbb{I} $

$A$ is a matrix e.g. shape 3x3

$b$ is a vector e.g. shape 3x1

$ \otimes $ is Kronecker product

$ \mathbb{I} $ is identity matrix

My questions are:

1. what is the shape of gradient: $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$
2. what is the definition of vector-value function with respect to matrix, since [Matrix Calculus Wikipedia doesn't have this type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scope)

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient ${\cal G}$ is a third-order tensor, so its shape is $(3\times 3\times 3)$.

This easiest to see using index notation.
$$\eqalign{
f_i &= A_{ij}b_j \\
df_i &= dA_{ij}b_j \\
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial A_{mn}}
 &= \bigg(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}\bigg)\,b_j \\
 &= \big(\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\big)\,b_j \\
 &= \delta_{im}b_n \\
 &= {\cal G}_{imn} \\
}$$
This assumes that the elements of $A$ are independent, so that $\Big(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}\Big)$ equals zero

unless $(i=m)\,\&\,(j=n)\,-$ which are the same conditions enforced by the delta symbols.

In order to write this without resorting to tensor/index notation, many authors flatten the $(3\times 3)$ $A$ matrix into a $(9\times 1)$ vector using the [Kronecker-vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) relationship.

Their derivation goes like so.
$$\eqalign{
f &= A\,b \\
df &= dA\,b \\
{\rm vec}(df) &= {\rm vec}(I\,dA\,b) \\
df &= (b^T\otimes I)\,da \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= (b^T\otimes I)
 \;= G \in {\mathbb R}^{3\times 9} \\
}$$
Then they call the $G$ matrix "the gradient" $-$ but it's really a *flattened* representation of the ${\cal G}$ tensor.